# PDAL dimensions in filter.sort

Tags: python, pdal

I am trying to sort by multiple dimensions using PDAL. I am getting an error stating

> RuntimeError: filters.sort: Attempted to set value twice for argument 'dimension'.

My code:

```
"type": "filters.sort",
"dimension": ["Z", "X", "Y"],
"order": ["ASC", "ASC", "ASC"]
```

is this type of sorting not supported in PDAL?